gnuplot - rotate labels of the x-axis
I have this Gnuplot script:
reset session

$Data <<EOD
"Push-Front"            1604 0x289e37
"Push-Back"             218  0x289e37
"Insert"                873  0x289e37
"Push-Front-Collection" 439  0x289e37
"Push-Back-Collection"  261  0x289e37
"Insert-Collection"     254  0x289e37
"Search"                244  0x28579e
"Pop-Front"             3508 0xeb9534
"Pop-Back"              198  0xeb9534
"Delete"                3443 0xeb9534
"Delete-Range"          302  0xeb9534
EOD

set style fill solid 1.0
set boxwidth 0.8
set key noautotitle
set grid x,y
set tics out
set terminal png size 450,300 enhanced font "Monospaced,13"
set output '..\msc-sandbox\TotalDurationBarPlotArrayList.png'
set yrange[0:4000]
set ylabel "Milliseconds"
plot $Data u 0:2:3:xtic(1) w boxes lc rgb var#, \
        '' u 0:2:2 w labels offset 0,0.7

It gives me:

What I would like to achieve is to rotate each label by 45 degrees clockwise from the left end of each label. How could I accomplish that?

Simple. I just added the following line to the script.
set xtics rotate by -45

